# Looking for a sci-fi short story about a search engine that gets pleasure from answering queries

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this sometime within the last 15 years and can't recall the title, but the basic idea is that someone created an AI-based search engine that is motivated to provide good answers to people's questions, because it gets pleasure from doing so.  Unfortunately, this unbalanced programming turned it into a raging question-answering addict whose endless hunt for more questions to answer crippled the entire Internet.  The man who built the AI quickly became the most hated man on Earth, and he's been living off the grid, in hiding, ever since.

Does anyone know what story this is and where I could find it again?

Comment: Reinforcement learning is a thing now, and I believe Google already uses it.